# How can I use Android DataBinding in a listview and still use a ViewHolder pattern?

Tags: java, android, listview, data-binding, android-viewholder

I have an Android activity that pulls its data from an observable list inside an adapter class.

My `getView()` method in my adapter class is:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    // Perform the binding
    ActivityTeamMessageListRowBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_activity_list_row, parent, false);
    binding.setInfo(list.get(position));
    binding.executePendingBindings();

    // Return the bound view
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

And this works great. However, I see the Android-warning *unconditional layout inflation from view adapter* on the `ActivityTeamMessageListRowBinding binding ...` line.

I have been researching **ViewHolders** to fix this issue, but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this and still use my data binding. And presumably, the longer the list, the worse performance I'd see without using a ViewHolder.

**Does anyone know how to extend my `getView(...)` code to incorporate a view binder?** I have a 3 `TextView`s and 1 `ImageView` in my *my_activity_list_row.xml*.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = ((Activity) parent.getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
    }

    // Perform the binding

    ActivityTeamMessageListRowBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(convertView);

    if (binding == null) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_activity_list_row, parent, false);
    }

    binding.setInfo(list.get(position));
    binding.executePendingBindings();

    // Return the bound view
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

I haven't used data binding with `ListView` (I'll use `RecyclerView`), but off the cuff, this is what I'd try. Use breakpoints or logging to confirm that, when `convertView` is not `null`, that you get `binding` back from `getBinding()` more often than not (and perhaps all the time — I'm hazy on how data binding's caching works).

Comment: How does a `ViewHolder` fit into this pattern?

Comment: @Brett: `ActivityTeamMessageListRowBinding` *is* the view holder. Part of what the data binding framework gives you is a code-generate view holder. You will have fields on the class that map to the widgets in `R.layout.my_activity_list_row`, based on their ID values. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#views_with_ids).

Answer (score 0):

DataBindingUtil already implement that

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getViewForResource(mResourceId, position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getViewForResource(mDropDownResourceId, position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getViewForResource(int resourceId, int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewDataBinding binding = (convertView != null) 
                    ? DataBindingUtil.getBinding(convertView) 
                    : DataBindingUtil.inflate(mLayoutInflater, resourceId, parent, false);
    binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, getItem(position));
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```